# No se actualiza mi base de datos cuando hago update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando actualizar un registro de mi base de datos pero me lanza un error particular.

Les comento como funciona: en mi controlador traigo los primeros 20 registros de mi tabla de compras. Luego verifico que un registro contenga un valor determinado, y luego intento actualizar el estado de ese registro a "Verificado".

El error que me dentro del mdlActualizarCompras es del siguiente tipo en la linea de if($stmt -> execute()){:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in...

Les dejo el código:

**CONTROLADOR:**

```
/*=============================================
MOSTRAR TABLA COMPRAS Y ACTUALIZAR
=============================================*/

static public function ctrMostrarCompras($verificacion){

    $tabla = "compras";
            $ordenar = "id";
            $modo = "DESC";

            $number = 10;

    $respuesta = ModeloCarrito::mdlMostrarCompras($tabla, $ordenar, $modo, $number);

    $compraEncontrada = 0;

    foreach ($respuesta as $key => $value) {

        if ($value["verificacion"] == $verificacion) {

            $compraEncontrada = 1;
            $id = $value["id"];

            break;

        } 

    }

    if ($compraEncontrada == 1){

                    $estado = "estado";

        $respuesta1 = ModeloCarrito::mdlActualizarCompra($tabla, $id, $estado);

        return $respuesta1;

    } else { return "NO ENCONTRE NADA";}

}
```

**MODELO**

```
/*=============================================
MOSTRAR COMPRAS
=============================================*/

static public function mdlMostrarCompras($tabla, $ordenar, $modo, $number){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY $ordenar $modo LIMIT $number");

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    $stmt -> close();

    $tmt =null;

}

/*=============================================
ACTUALIZAR COMPRA
=============================================*/

static public function mdlActualizarCompra($tabla, $id, $estado){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET estado = :estado WHERE id =:id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":estado", "Verificado", PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error"; 

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error suele significar que se esperaba una variable en el argumento 2. Intuyo que el problema esta en esta línea

```
 $stmt->bindParam(":estado", "Verificado", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Prueba a asignar el String "Verificado" a una variable;

```
$verificado="Verificado";     
$stmt->bindParam(":estado", $verificado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Espero que te solucione el problema.
Un saludo :D